# FactoryBotの関連付けで常に同一の親を持つように設定する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`FactoryBot`の関連付けの記述で常に同一の親を指定する方法がわからなかったので質問します。

以下のような関係のモデルがあり

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trades
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trades
end

class Trade < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end
```

テストのために以下のような記述をしています。

#### test/factries.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.safe_email }
    password { Faker::Internet.password }
  end

  factory :company do
    code { Faker::Number.unique.number(4) }
  end

  factory :trade do
    sequence(:order_number)
    user
    company
  end
end
```

### test/models/trade_test.rb

```
class TradeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @company = create(:company)
    @user = create(:user)
  end

  test 'Foo' do
    create(:trade, user: @user, company: @company, price: 200)
    create(:trade, user: @user, company: @company, price: 100)
    assert(@user.foo)
  end
end
```

ほとんどのテストにおいて上記のように`trade`を生成する時に同一の`user`と`company`を指定するのですが、常に`user: @user, company: @company`を記述するのは冗長なのでもっとスッキリかけないかと思っています。

`Factory.define`か`setup`内で`Trade`を作成する時はデフォルトで同じ親を持つように指定する方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一番手っ取り早いのは

```rb
factory :trade do
  sequence(:order_number)
  user { User.first || create(:user) }
  company { Company.first || create(:company) }
end

...
test 'Foo' do
  create(:trade, price: 200)
  create(:trade, price: 100)
  assert(@user.foo)
end
```

とすることだと思います。
ただこうしてしまうと、テストケースを見ただけでは同じ親を持つtradeだといういうことが分からないので、せめてfacotry定義を継承して作っておいた方が無難だと思います。

```rb
factory :trade do
  sequence(:order_number)

  factory :trade_with_the_same_parents do
    user { User.first || create(:user) }
    company { Company.first || create(:company) }
  end
end

...

  create(:trade_with_the_same_parents, price: 200)
  create(:trade_with_the_same_parents, price: 100)
```

その他、factory_botの`transient`やコールバックを利用しても書けると思います。
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

あるいはファクトリ定義はシンプルに保ち、テスト用のヘルパーメソッドを作成するという手もあると思います。

ただ、個人的には現状通りの方法で良いのではないかと思います。。。
アプリの規模が大きくなると、ファクトリ定義ってすぐに複雑になっちゃいますし、あまりテストコード周りで凝りすぎてしまうと、テストを読むのに解析が必要になるという本末転倒な結果に陥ったりもしますし。
テストコードは冗長であっても明示的に保ち、DRYを求めすぎないというバランスも大事だと思います。

Comment: なるほど、色々方法があるんですね。今回はアドバイスいただいた通り現状維持にしておこうと思います。ありがとうございました。